# xsltProcessor.transformToFragment support in Microsoft Edge with inline DTD

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xslt, microsoft-edge

My question is a follow up on: [32958539](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958539/xsltprocessor-transformtofragment-support-in-ie-edge)

The question is how to make it work in Microsoft EDGE with inline DTD. Has anyone figured out a way to accomplish this?

I have tried the [example](http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2015/XSLTProcessorTest1.html) that [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) has contributed and made a small modification in file test2015100601.xsl. I've added `<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> <!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;"> ] >` to the top of the file. The result is NULL.

transformToDocument result: null.

transformToFragment result: null.

Comment: It should be `<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [...]>`, I think. I have not tested whether that improves things.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately the result remains NULL.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I also tried some stuff but I don't know how to get that to work, I guess the implementors of Edge simply overlooked that MSXML 6, the XSLT processor they use to provide XSLT support, by default prevents DTD use for security reasons and any XSLT trying to use such a document needs to enable it first. Probably, at least when handing over the IE XML DOM to MSXML 6 to run the XSLT, the DTD processing is not enabled and that way the transformation fails completely. But that is a pure guess, I don't know how Edge uses MSXML 6 under the hood.

Comment: I have reported the issue as https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2030537, let's see when and how they react.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Perhaps it is worth noting that this bug is present in EDGE 12 and EDGE 13.

Comment: Martin, are you able to reopen the feedback? TH2 does not solve this. I've got a windows 10 1511 10586.11 with EDGE 13 and your testcase is failing.

Comment: Consider to comment yourself on that issue on the connect page or to open a new issue, I am afraid I am not even sure what TH2 is and as I can't test with anything but my normal Window 10 system I don't feel like reopening the feedback. If you have access to prerelease or test versions of Edge and you can identify the issue then please report it yourself.